# Почему блоки накладываются друг на друга?

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать на каждом блоке параллакс эффект при скролле.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#welcome,
#how,
#day {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

#welcome_tittle,
#how_tittle,
#day_tittle {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 15vw;
  color: #FFF;
}

#welcome,
#how,
#day,
#welcome:before,
#how:before,
#day:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

#welcome::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517694712202-14dd9538aa97?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  animation: backgroundAnimate 1s linear infinite;
}

#how::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555099962-4199c345e5dd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  animation: backgroundAnimate 1s linear infinite;
}

#day::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550439062-609e1531270e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  animation: backgroundAnimate 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome">
  <h1 id="welcome_tittle">Hello Stranger!</h1>
</section>
<section id="how">
  <h1 id="how_tittle">How are you?</h1>
</section>
<section id="day">
  <h1 id="day_tittle">Have a nice day!</h1>
</section>
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему блоки наложились друг на друга и как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста вставляйте код во встроенную песочницу, не надо ссылок. Я бы исправил но сейчас не имею возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я ответ написал не по вашему коду, но скажу так - что на css хоть как бы и проще в плане производительности но сложнее в понимании..
На javascript этот эффект при скроле легче воспроизвести но ответ мой на css

> скролл хорошо видно если тянуть за скроллбар и смотреть на полный экран

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Nunito;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transform-style: inherit;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240, 230, 220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

img:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240, 230, 220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slide,
.slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#title {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/");
  z-index: 2;
}

#title h1 {
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/3/");
  z-index: 2;
}

#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/5/");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}

#slide4 {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div id="title" class="slide header">
  <h1>Pure CSS Parallax</h1>
</div>

<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id
      viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id
      viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/6/">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract/4/">
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id
      viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slide4" class="slide header">
  <h1>The End</h1>
</div>
```